# How to change what sequence will be used by postgresql when it gets next value for id?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 table with field `id` which automatic created by `sequelize`.

```
table1
id integer not null default nextval('table1_d_seq'::regclass)

table2
id integer not null default nextval('table2_d_seq'::regclass)
```

Could I tune `sequelize` to create `id` field in `table2` with modifier `nextval('table1_d_seq'::regclass)` ?

Comment: not relevant, but might help - SQL: `alter table table2 alter column id set default nextval('table1_d_seq'::regclass);`

Comment: @VaoTsun, yes, I could execute query but I want create migration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a migration file which will change specified column and set it's default value via the `sequelize.query()` method available through `queryInterface`

```
module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize){

        return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
            "ALTER TABLE table2 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table1_d_seq'::regclass)"
        );

    },

    down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {

    }
}
```